# Error in CellEndEdit code when i'm click in other cell

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I'm using this code in CellEndEdit:

```
if ((dataGridView1.Columns[dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex].Name == "Column1"))
{
    dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1[1, 0];  
}
```

If I'm in Edit mode(not in selection mode) and I click in another cell I get the error:

> InvalidOperationExpection was unhandled

See below image for an example of what I am explaining:

[image: DatagridviewSample]

I tried something like this with no result:

```
private void dataGridView1_CellClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    dataGridView1.CellEndEdit += new DataGridViewCellEventHandler(dataGridView1_CellEndEdit);
}
```

Comment: Sorry my answer did not work, Good Luck!

Answer (score 0):

Details error

> Operation is not valid because it results in a reentrant call to the SetCurrentCellAddressCore function.

so You can resolve this problem using `BeginInvoke` like this.

```
   private void dataGridView1_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        if ((dataGridView1.Columns[dataGridView1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex].Name == "Column1"))
        {
            this.BeginInvoke(new MethodInvoker(() =>
            {
                dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1[1, 0];
            }));
        }
    }
```

`Control.BeginInvoke`  method - here you find [doc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pl-pl/library/0b1bf3y3(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Executes the specified delegate asynchronously on the thread that the control's underlying handle was created on.

Comment: It works but when i'm in edit mode and i'm  clicking with mouse to another cell it runs the code. Example if its in first cell edit mode and i 'm clicking to third cell it selects second cell

Comment: You probably need call `dataGridView1.BeginEdit(true);` after set current cell

Comment: I tried it same issue. Is there any code wich accepts edit?and turns it to selection mode?